# Get current seller id by product id in magento 2 marketplace

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get current seller id by product id in magento 2. 
I am try this also but its not useful for me.

```
public function getMy(){

if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
         $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
          $seller_id= $customerData->getId();
     }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter($seller_id);
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        return $collection;

    }
```

I also try this

```
$collection = $objectManager->create(
                        'Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Product'
                    )
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter(
                        'mageproduct_id',
                        $id
                    );
```

Please help me..

Comment: Your question is not clear. We cant use 'Mage' class in magento 1 and your second try well give output of products. I am confused that what u want to say by current seller.

Comment: I have multiple seller in magento 2 marketplace. how i get Current seller id by product id.I just asked this.

Comment: Check database there must be an relation between seller id and product id, base on that u can call seller collection by filter with product id.

Comment: Thank You for advise but in which table of database.